# How to write htaccess - mod_rewrite rules for retrieving querystring values in multiple languages?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, utf-8, multilingual

**RewriteRule**

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9%_-]+)([\.|\/|@|%])([a-zA-Z0-9%_-]+)/$ index.php?t=$1&v=$2&q=$3 [QSA]
```

This is an attempt to capture query string values. How should I replace

```
[a-zA-Z0-9%_-]
```

such that all `UTF-8` or for that matter `UTF-16` values are considered valid inputs?

Environment is `Apache2 - PHP 5.6+`

Incoming queries:

1. `example.com/query/información@importante`
2. `example.com/query/महत्वपूर्ण@जानकारी`
3. `example.com/query/முக்கியமான@தகவல்`
4. `example.com/query/důležitá@informace`

Expected variables:

- `t=información`
- `v=@`
- `q=importante`

Comment: @anubhava, ideally, in addition to expected language localisation, other characters in query string could also be retrieved accurately?

Comment: Since I am referencing a base of index.php, which sits in the query directory as a real directory. But it does not have to be. I am not sure of the significance. I could just as well use other rewrites to redirect the base url also. I guess at issue is the input that is there in the regex expression.?

Comment: So `index.php` in inside `query` sub-directory ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule in `query/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/@]+)(@)([^/]+)/?$ index.php?t=$1&v=$2&q=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: `[^/@]` means match any char except `/` and `@`